# How does this prime generator code work on the first round of the loop when n=2?

Tags: python, generator, primes

I am studying generators in python. I follow the code from https://jakevdp.github.io/WhirlwindTourOfPython/12-generators.html but totally confused by the program when `n=2`, what exactly is the result of `all(n % p > 0 for p in primes)`?
Per my understand, the first round of the loop, `primes` is empty. So how come the expression is True and adding `2` to the set?

```
def gen_primes(N):
    """Generate primes up to N"""
    primes = set()
    for n in range(2, N):
        if all(n % p > 0 for p in primes):
            primes.add(n)
            yield n

print(*gen_primes(100))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

> Return `True` if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty)

So when `primes` is empty, `n % p > 0 for p in primes` is empty because there's nothing to iterate over. Therefore `all()` returns `True`, and `n` is added to `primes`.

Comment: What is the result of ``2 % p >0``?

Comment: `2 % p` is the remainder when `2` is divided by `p`. If `2` is a multiple of `p`, the remainder is `0`, otherwise it's more than `0`. So That tells you if `2` is a multiple of `p`.

Comment: A prime number is a number that isn't a multiple of any other primes.

Comment: What I do not understand is, what the value of ``p``? The set is empty, so ``p`` supposed to not a number,  expression in the first loop is ``2`%None`` or what?

Comment: When the set is empty, there's no `p`.

Comment: The expression is never executed, because there's nothing to iterate over. It just returns an empty iterator, and `all()` returns `True`.